# how do i automagicly create a dict in my editor with keys 0-100

Tags: python, dictionary

I want to create a dictionary with keys 0-1000.
I want to use this dict as a "database" to store hardcoded data

#### Question

Doing this by hand costs a fair bit of time.
Is there a way I can do this automatically?

#### Example

```py
usernames: dict = {
    0: "",
    1: "",
    2: "",
    3: "",
    4: "",
    5: "",
    6: "",
    7: "",
    8: "",
    9: "",
    10: "",
    # and so on ...
    1000: ""
}
```

Comment: Why wouldn't you just use a length 1001 (or 101) `list` with indices 0-1000 (or 100)?  Note your title and question content conflict on the size.

Comment: Not much difference between a dictionary with numerically contiguous keys and a list.  Also the list can initialized with just `usernames = [""] * 1001`.

Comment: @JordyV I suggest using an actual database then. Or a file. Data should be stored separately from code.

Comment: Assuming you need the skeleton to manually add to you can print out the raw lines, copy, paste into the dict. otherwise i'd recommend comprehension to build your dict. `for i in range(1000): print(f"{i}: ''")`

Answer (score 4):

Use the classmethod factory [`fromkeys`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dict.fromkeys):

```
dict.fromkeys(range(1001), "")
```

And perhaps consider using a list. This is more memory efficient than using a dict with consecutive integer keys.

```
[""] * 1001
```

Comment: Although the list-recommendation might appear unhandy when focusing on a _key_ to get the user, the addressing of elements with a numerical key might be the same - compare: `user_dict[indexNum]` vs `user_list[indexNum]` for example `indexNum = 0`

Answer (score 3):

Consider using comprehension

```py
usernames: dict = {idx: "" for idx in range(1001)}
```

Answer (score 2):

This looks like the kind of thing you should do programmatically rather than manually editing a file. For sequential numeric keys, consider using a list instead of a dict.

If you really need a dict, then use a dict comprehension as Demitri shows or `defaultdict` which allows you to provide a default value for any key that isn't explicitly set in the dict.

If you have some data other than just empty strings, then consider reading the data from an external file rather than putting it in code. Generally, data should be stored separately from code anyway.

Answer (score 2):

Start by creating a dictionary:

```
dictionary = {}
```

Now you can use a for loop to create the keys:

```
for num in range(1001):
    dictionary[num] = ""
```

Comment: Not the most efficient way to do it, but the easiest one to understand. Congrats for your first post!

Comment: @Andrew believe only changes needed to make is `range(1000)` and `[num]`

Comment: Thanks @wim and rv.kvetch for the advice!

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your use-case:

> want to use this dict as a "database" to store hardcoded data

#### The database approach

Most databases don't reserve space upfront and create something like dummy-records. Nor do they create and reserve keys in advance.

What a typical database and the setup for a collection or table of users would do:

1. create the schema or table `user` with columns or fields `id` for the key or sequential number, `name` more for the attributes.
2. create the sequence or auto-numbering to generate a new `id` value for each newly added or inserted record

#### The data structure approach in Python

Analogously you would create either a dict with some functions to manage:

```py
user_store = {}  # empty dict, no schema, no elements yet

current_id = None  # the sequence to increment for each new record added

def nextId():
    if not current_id:
       current_id = 0  # the initial first value of the sequence
    else:
       current_id += 1  # increment each time

    return current_id

def add_user(name):
    id = nextId()  # generate unique id from sequence
    user_store[id] = name  # add new key with value 
    return id  # return the generated id to reference the user record later 

def remove_user_by_id(id):
    del user_store[id]  # frees space

def update_user(id, new_name):
    user_store[id] = new_name  # update the name


def count():
    # there may be records and ids deleted, so the count is not related to current_id
    return len(user_store)
```

See also:

- RealPython: [Dictionaries in Python](https://realpython.com/python-dicts)

If the (primary) *key*  or id is a sequential number starting with 0 you can also use a list instead a dict.

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
usernames = {}
for i in range(0, 100):
    usernames[i] = ""
```